# 5.1 HDMI Mixed Channels, Stuttering/Choppy Audio

Tags: sound, 13.10, pulseaudio, hdmi, alsa

I've bought an Intel Core i3 4130 with a Gigabyte H87N-WIFI motherboard with the intention of creating an HTPC. I'm trying out Ubuntu 13.10 on a live USB and everything works except for 5.1 Surround audio.

I get this error when testing out individual speakers: [link](https://vimeo.com/81954892)

Front left, right, centre and LFE play in their correct speakers but rear left and right play out of front left and right respectively. When I choose Digital Stereo the audio plays fine.

I'd play out of Digital Optical S/PDIF but it doesn't seem to support 5.1 for some reason, and my surround system doesn't support mixing HDMI video and optical audio sources.

I've searched almost everywhere and haven't been able to find anyone who has experienced a similar issue. Please fire away with any suggestions you may have!

aplay -l:

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: MID [HDA Intel MID], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: MID [HDA Intel MID], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: MID [HDA Intel MID], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC892 Analog [ALC892 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 1: ALC892 Digital [ALC892 Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

aplay -L:

```
default
    Playback/recording through the PulseAudio sound server
hdmi:CARD=MID,DEV=0
    HDA Intel MID, HDMI 0
    HDMI Audio Output
hdmi:CARD=MID,DEV=1
    HDA Intel MID, HDMI 1
    HDMI Audio Output
hdmi:CARD=MID,DEV=2
    HDA Intel MID, HDMI 2
    HDMI Audio Output
dmix:CARD=MID,DEV=3
    HDA Intel MID, HDMI 0
    Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=MID,DEV=7
    HDA Intel MID, HDMI 1
    Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=MID,DEV=8
    HDA Intel MID, HDMI 2
    Direct sample mixing device
dsnoop:CARD=MID,DEV=3
    HDA Intel MID, HDMI 0
    Direct sample snooping device
dsnoop:CARD=MID,DEV=7
    HDA Intel MID, HDMI 1
    Direct sample snooping device
dsnoop:CARD=MID,DEV=8
    HDA Intel MID, HDMI 2
    Direct sample snooping device
hw:CARD=MID,DEV=3
    HDA Intel MID, HDMI 0
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
hw:CARD=MID,DEV=7
    HDA Intel MID, HDMI 1
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
hw:CARD=MID,DEV=8
    HDA Intel MID, HDMI 2
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
plughw:CARD=MID,DEV=3
    HDA Intel MID, HDMI 0
    Hardware device with all software conversions
plughw:CARD=MID,DEV=7
    HDA Intel MID, HDMI 1
    Hardware device with all software conversions
plughw:CARD=MID,DEV=8
    HDA Intel MID, HDMI 2
    Hardware device with all software conversions
sysdefault:CARD=PCH
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC892 Analog
    Default Audio Device
front:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC892 Analog
    Front speakers
surround40:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC892 Analog
    4.0 Surround output to Front and Rear speakers
surround41:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC892 Analog
    4.1 Surround output to Front, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround50:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC892 Analog
    5.0 Surround output to Front, Center and Rear speakers
surround51:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC892 Analog
    5.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround71:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC892 Analog
    7.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Side, Rear and Woofer speakers
iec958:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC892 Digital
    IEC958 (S/PDIF) Digital Audio Output
dmix:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC892 Analog
    Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=PCH,DEV=1
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC892 Digital
    Direct sample mixing device
dsnoop:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC892 Analog
    Direct sample snooping device
dsnoop:CARD=PCH,DEV=1
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC892 Digital
    Direct sample snooping device
hw:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC892 Analog
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
hw:CARD=PCH,DEV=1
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC892 Digital
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
plughw:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC892 Analog
    Hardware device with all software conversions
plughw:CARD=PCH,DEV=1
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC892 Digital
    Hardware device with all software conversions
```

Comment: I have the same problem, with Ubuntu 12.04 and other hardware but also using the Intel HD graphics card.

Comment: I just noticed the same thing with a brand new intel nuk kit (i5 hd graphics 5000 - model D54250wyk.) with audio over hdmi. stereo over hdmi works fine.
when I switch to 5.1 over hdmi the audio also works but chops very badly all channels ubuntu 13.1 very latest updates. Also did a bios update on the intel nuc to make sure this was not a problem that was already fixed. Update. I reproduced stuttering audio on ubuntu 13.1 and mint 16. Both of which work (5.1 over hdmi) correctly on an older board with intel chipset (a jetway board with i5). So something specific to NUC and linux. Anyone have an

Answer (score 0):

I installed the 3.13.3 kernel on 12.04 and since then it worked fine. I'm not a crack enough to determine if that can be improved or if it is recommended for a productive system. But it also fixed another issue I had with HDMI.

http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.13.3-trusty/